# Por que é possível pra abrir portas seriais (COM) no Windows usando funções de arquivo?

Tags: windows, arquivo, independente-de-linguagem, porta-serial

Como isso acontece? Existe outras formas de abrir ou só essa  Digo, em linguagens como C, PHP, Python, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque elas são arquivos. Ou pelo menos uma forma de. Não é só no Windows. Facilita muito para o sistema operacional tratar certos dispositivos como se fossem arquivos. Afinal o que você vai fazer em um arquivo é o mesmo que faria no dispositivo, ler e escrever dados.

Arquivos, do ponto de vista do usuário, são *streams* de dados, onde eles estão fisicamente não importa, a não ser para as camadas mais baixas do sistema operacional.

Esta é a forma disponível no sistema operacional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: como seria o caminho desse arquivo no windows? eu tento \\\\.\\COM mas ele só consegue abrir e escrever e não consegue dizer se existe, ler...

Comment: Em geral ela existe. Como o ideal é não verificar a existência de algo e sim tentar usar e ver se dá algum erro, assim evitando uma *race condition*, não precisa ter uma forma de verificar. O que pode ser feito é listar todos os dispositivos existentes para saber se ele será usado. O "arquivo" COM existe.

Comment: sim, mas como farei pra ler? pois tenho que passar o caminho do arquivo, porém ele n identifica ou diz que não é permitido a operação, qual seria o caminho do "arquivo"

Comment: Aí você tem que fazer outra pergunta, dizer que linguagem está usando, etc. Mas o caminho é "COM1", "COM2", etc.